# No EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN in wx.aui

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to add a right click event handler for a AuiNotebook ctrl. In the document, it says AuiNotebook can emit a EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN event. But when I try to bind the event to notebook, I get the following error:

'module' object has no attribute 'EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN'

What's the problem? wxPython doesn't support it?

I'm on Mac OS X and using wxPython 2.9.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (I don't know why) it uses a double underscore,

i.e. you have to use

EVT__AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN

For anyone else that is interested these are the events that the AuiNotebook appears to have as of wxPython 2.9.4(.1)

```
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_ALLOW_DND
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_BEGIN_DRAG
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_BG_DCLICK
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_BUTTON
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_DRAG_DONE
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_DRAG_MOTION
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_END_DRAG
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGING
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE
EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED
EVT__AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_MIDDLE_DOWN
EVT__AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_MIDDLE_UP
EVT__AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN
EVT__AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_UP
```